# How to pem encode an ethereum privateKey with go？

Tags: ethereum, private-key, pem

I have the following code：

```
func newAddress() string {
    privKey, _ := crypto.GenerateKey()
    publicKey := privKey.Public()
    publicKeyECDSA, _ := publicKey.(*ecdsa.PublicKey)
    address := crypto.PubkeyToAddress(*publicKeyECDSA).Hex()
    return address
}
```

Now I want to pem encode the publicKey and privatekey and save:

```
func newAddress() string {
    privKey, _ := crypto.GenerateKey()
    publicKey := privKey.Public()
    publicKeyECDSA, _ := publicKey.(*ecdsa.PublicKey)
    address := crypto.PubkeyToAddress(*publicKeyECDSA).Hex()
    x509EncodedPri, _ := x509.MarshalECPrivateKey(privKey)
    block := pem.Block{
        Type:    "ECDSA Private Key",
        Headers: nil,
        Bytes:   x509EncodedPri,
    }
    file, err := os.Create("eccPrivate.pem")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()
    pem.Encode(file, &block)
    return address
}
```

I found it empty：

```
$ cat  eccPrivate.pem
-----BEGIN ECDSA Private Key-----
-----END ECDSA Private Key-----
```

I know I should use `ecdsa.GenerateKey(elliptic.P256(), rand.Reader)` to generate the private key, but I end up with a different address than `crypto.GenerateKey()`.
If anyone can tell me where I am going wrong, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: An Ethereum address and an ECDSA public key are related. The key can be PEM encoded. Why do you think the Ethereum address can be PEM encoded?

Comment: I don't want to encode the address, what I want to do is encode the privateKey and the publicKey, Take a look at the code.

Comment: The X509 package supports only the EC curves P-224, P-256, P-384 and P-521 (see [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/crypto/x509/x509.go#L481)), but not secp256k1. However, the corresponding methods can be adapted with little effort.